# Group by with distinct count in DAX PowerBI

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, distinct, calculated-columns

how can I count the number of different companies for each user / activity_desc / activity combination?
I tried with that dax but it doesn't work; THNAKS
[image: S1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Column =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[company] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[user], 'Table'[activity], 'Table'[activity_desc] )
)
```